# How to check intersection in libgdx?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have two sprites with two textures. How to check if they are intersecting ?
I am using libgdx 0.9.8.

Comment: Any code snippet please...

Comment: I'm really wondering why people so often mark questions as off-topic, just because THEY don't understand the question. The only information needed here was the library, and it's even tagged correctly.

Comment: its pointless @noone moderators wont listen us

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if (sprite1.getBoundingRectangle().contains(Sprite2.getBoundingRectangle())
{
    //gives true when sprite2 one is completly inside sprite1
}
```

also

```
if(sprite1.getBoundingRectangle().overlaps(Sprite2.getBoundingRectangle())
{
    // gives true when sprite 2 intersects sprite1
}
```

Comment: just giving a rough idea as i have no idea about your code

Comment: I'd like to  know any such methods available for animations.

Answer (score 3):

The [`Intersector`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Intersector.html) has a lot of methods to check for overlaps and intersection in general. There are not just methods for rectangles, but also circles, points, polygons etc.

In your case you could use the following:

```
Rectangle boundingRect1 = sprite1.getBoundingRectangle();
Rectangle boundingRect2 = sprite2.getBoundingRectangle();

if (Intersector.overlaps(boundingRect1, boundingRect2)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: @noone I never really felt used of Intersector for rectangles when rectangle itself has coantains and overlaps. But then for polynomial its a life saver.

Comment: Yes, it's a matter of taste. If you have other shapes then you need the intersector anyway, so you can also just use when you have rectangles.